# Find boundaries to separate peaks in a 3D plot using matlab or python

Tags: matlab, python

Could you tell me how to find boundaries to separate the peaks in the 3D plot below? Ideally, the boundaries are at the local minimum. Peaks can be generated using Gaussian distributions with some noise. As the top view shows, Gaussians are not in perfect grids, so cannot be seperated by straight lines.  The lines are only drawn to illustrate the concept of seperation.  The problem is that sometimes noise can be high, so it is difficult to find peaks and valleys precisely.

[top view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Mj4.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to MSE. This is a good, but vague, question, and thes often get lots of comments that ask you to clarify the question so that we can better help you. These aren't criticisms --- they're an attempt to save everyone time. Only once a question is mathematically precise can you hope to get an "answer" rather than an opinion. My own clarifying question is this: Can you give an idea of what you're looking for? If I blur my eyes a little, I see 18 peaks. If I look closely, I see about 100. If the Gaussians were smaller and the noise a little larger, there'd probably be 500 peaks.

Comment: BTW, as you answer questions like mine, you can alter your original question by clicking on "edit" just below the question, so that it gradually becomes clearer and clearer, and later potential answer-givers don't need to read the comment thread.

Comment: The problem would be simple if there was no noise, right? Simply look for zero crossings in the derivatives, or use hill climbing if you like. The presence of noise makes it hard, because the more noise the more local peaks, which makes the problem ambiguous. Therefore, in my point of view, the real question you should ask (yourself) is how to get rid of the noise effectively. Smoothing/low pass filtering could be an answer, but it heavily depends on the underlying problem what exactly one can do. Without further elaborations, the help we can offer is very limited.